# switch from 64-bit long mode to 32-bit compatibility mode on x64

Tags: x86-64, uefi

I want to switch from 64-bit long mode to 32-bit compatibility mode (and back) in a UEFI boot application.
Changing bit L in the code segment descriptor seems not enough.
What are the other steps? Is there an example?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot switch in 32bit mode in UEFI. Even if you switch the CPU and reboot the machine the UEFI will blow up! Because the rest of the UEFI firmware (BIOS) expects x64 mode. There is only one way is to create a 32bit virtual machine that will run 32bit applications. That's exactly what 64bit Windows does running 32bit apps.

Comment: switching into 32-bit compatibility mode works fine. Of course, one has to switch back to 64-bit mode when calling a UEFI service.

Comment: But consider what 32-bit windows does if loaded from UEFI. If the 32-bit kernel is being started in long mode it would "blow up" and in compatibility mode it would not be able to enter virtual x86 mode. So what's probably done is that the boot loader actually switches to legacy mode before starting the windows kernel. You only have to make sure that the boot loader is running in correct mode when calling UEFI and correct mode when starting 32-bit kernel.

Comment: @user2707695 I hate when people give you a "minus" but have no actual clue what they are talking about. Read the question carefully "...to switch from 64-bit long mode to 32-bit compatibility mode (and back) in a UEFI boot application", key here is "UEFI Boot Application". I will repeat myself! You CANNOT switch CPU into 32 bit mode while in UEFI environment. Period. It will blow up. Even though UEFI is single-thread environment and it doesn't have interrupts it is driver-based architecture and drivers use notification mechanism for hardware - software communicate.

Comment: @skyking Microsoft UEFI Boot Loader is 64bit UEFI Application. That's the hard fact. When MS Kernel stars its execution the UEFI is long time gone. UEFI app loads another loader (I have no idea what type of application it is but my guess is legacy) and when it starts UEFI is gone already, then this loader prepares the system/hardware for MS Kernel, loads it, and passes the execution to the Kernel.

Comment: @Alex That's probably correct, but `ntldr` would probably as well expect to be started in legacy mode (it may even expect to be started in real mode). The fact therefore remains - the UEFI boot loader has to be able to switch to legacy mode in order to invoke the `ntldr`. The fact remains regardless of which phase of the boot sequence it commences at since it's a step that's expects to be started in legacy mode.

Comment: @Alex Speaking of people that have no actual clue what they are talking about, you should read about the [Compatibility Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Operating_modes) sub-mode of x86-64 Long Mode. WOW64 in fact uses Compatibility Mode, to run 32-bit applications, and certainly not a "virtual machine" as you indicated.....  Furthermore, *"When MS Kernel stars its execution the UEFI is long time gone"* is absolutely incorrect. Apparently you've never heard of UEFI Runtime Services, which the Windows and Linux kernels use to access UEFI Variables.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That's exactly what I meant! Some people have no clue whatsoever! WOW64 is the x86 emulator and it runs in user mode!

Comment: @Alex No, I was refering to you. It's not an emulator. Windows 64-bit runs 32-bit applications using Compatibilty Mode, a sub-mode of Long Mode in the CPU. 32-bit system calls thunk back to 64-bit via the WOW64 compatibility layer, and actually perform 64-bit system calls. There's no VM as you indicated.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I was referring to you when I said some people have no clue! Read msdn documentation and particularly WOW64 implementation specifics! However, the mechanism you described how the calls are thunk are correct though. But WOW64 is an EMULATOR! It emulates x86 instructions! CPU runs in 64bit mode always! No switching is performed! Emulation... emulator... rings a bell? It's sort of a VM! 32bit apps are running in USER MODE with 32bit memory layout. It's bad that you don't see the analogy! In win10 MS went even further. The whole freacking 64bit kernel is a VM for security reasons

Comment: @Alex You have literally *no idea* what you're talking about. From the [WoW64 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Architectures): 

*the Wow64win.dll's functions on the x86-64 architecture... switches the processor hardware from its 64-bit mode to compatibility mode when it becomes necessary to execute a 32-bit thread, and then handles the switch back to 64-bit mode.*

There is no emulation on x86-64.  (There *was* x86 emulation on the Itanium, but that's an entirely different processor.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ok, you are right! I admit my incompetence in that topic and that I had no clue! Now I will know! :) Thank you. And of course I know about UEFI RS. But that's not what we were talking about. Runtime Services is a tiny part of UEFI leftover and it doesn't use timer or interrupts from hardware that will crush the system if you switch the CPU into 32 bit mode unless you make a call to that services. We were talking about that UEFI will crush if you switch CPU from x64 long mode. You have to disable all UEFI interrupts and timers first and I can see little reason for doing this.